# Adding 2 Fields (Salary and PF) as result of Net Pay using Event Receiver in SP

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to add 2 fields (Salary + PF) as NET PAY using Item Added Event Receiver in SharePoint

Like NET PAY = [Salary] + [PF]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an event handler for this case is overkill. You can easily achieve the same result with a calculated field.

[Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the Information ! But the intention is like want to achieve this using Item Added Event Receiver. Please Suggest if any!